# Star Citizen Launcher Conflict

Tags: windows, taskmanager

Not sure where to ask this. Here it goes. I get this glitch . Seems there are many instances of the launcher running when i press it once. Is this a frame work, or some other environment im missing thats causing this ?
Unsure .
     Video showing . 
     https://youtu.be/W5j3JGL945o

Attempting to sign in just results in a endless trying to connect screen, and the audio remains distorted.

Trying to close out the 3 visible instances in Task Manager one at a time  (i found this is Normal ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got the answer from the RSI forum .

Windows %appdata% folder. In here you should see a couple folders named : 
rsilauncher and "RSI .  Deleted these two folders.

This allowed me to play the game.  The strange sound effects happens for a second still. But fades and the music plays normally for the launcher .

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether your Firewall or Antivirus is blocking the connection? The sound cue indicates when the launcher is trying to connect to the AWS servers. It probably gets blocked at some stage.

Also it is probably better to take this up with their customer support.
https://support.robertsspaceindustries.com/hc/en-us